# List item not able to retain class

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery code in ASP.NET for changing class of list item when clicking it. The code is working fine but the problem is that the `<li>` changes class for a little while, but it's not able to retain when the code is fully loaded. My code is like this:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu_nav">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="default.aspx"><span>Home Page</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="support.aspx"><span>Support</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.aspx"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="services.aspx"><span>Services</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.aspx"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: 'li changes class for a little while is isnot able to retain when the code is fully loaded' what do you mean?

Comment: if im not mistaken then $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); is only removing the class from the first LI not all?

Comment: do u mean that it works for some time and then stops ??

Comment: @Ladineko - You're mistaken ;)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I think he means as soon as he clicks the menu it will go to a different page but active will not be set to that menu item as soon as the page is loaded.

Comment: I suggest since you use ASP.NET that you can check on what page/url you are on and then add the active class to the correct menu item.

Comment: frendz i mean I used addclass in place of remove class then I saw all the the li's changed to white as metioned in class when I clicked on ne li but came to normal when I released moused.....

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, see here jsfiddle.net/S3hGq/

But after clicking, your browser loads the url, cause it's a link. And after reload, the 'active'-class is of course not set anymore.

Is it that what happens? Give me some more Information to help you...

Comment: is your project a php project? do you have php to set the active class to the loaded site's link? otherwise, if only javascript can describe your solution make it like @ShadowWizard does. Something with window.location.href and find the link similar to the loaded page and than set active.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong approach. You need to either "remember" the last anchor clicked (based on id for example) or read the current document location and based on that highlight the proper item.

I will give code for the second approach:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //read current page:
    var page = document.location.href.split("/").splice(-1,1);

    //find proper item and mark it active:
    $("ul.tabs li a[href='" + page + "']").addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give an id to all `li` tags.  same as page title on which it is linked e.g li with link to dashboard.aspx should have dashboard as id and also dashboard.aspx should have title as dashboard and then write this code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function changeClass() {
        document.getElementById(document.title).setAttribute("class", "current");
    }
</script>
```

Here in this code I find the title of the page by id and then  set class to the linked li

Answer (score 0):

Some frameworks like Struts 2 and Spring MVC for java say JavaScript that I shared earlier is obslete, so I came up with the new version of the same functionality in jquery.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
          var testtitle=$('title').text();
          $("#"+testtitle).addClass('current');
          }); 
    </script>
```